# Ordering of py.test functions results in failure

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm teaching an introduction to programming course using Python. I am using py.test to grade student work. I have a situation where the py.test reports a failed test case when the test functions are in one order, but reports passing when the test functions are in another order.

I've created a [project on Github](https://github.com/benevolentprof/pytest_wierdness.git) with the failing program and test code. But here's an excerpt from the test program.

```
from exercise3 import union, intersection, difference

###########
# TABLES ##
###########
GRADUATES = [["Number", "Surname", "Age"],
             [7274, "Robinson", 37],
             [7432, "O'Malley", 39],
             [9824, "Darkes", 38]]

MANAGERS = [["Number", "Surname", "Age"],
            [9297, "O'Malley", 56],
            [7432, "O'Malley", 39],
            [9824, "Darkes", 38]]


#####################
# HELPER FUNCTIONS ##
#####################
def is_equal(t1, t2):
    return sorted(t1) == sorted(t2)


###################
# TEST FUNCTIONS ##
###################


def test_union():
    """
    Test union operation.
    """

    result = [["Number", "Surname", "Age"],
              [7274, "Robinson", 37],
              [9297, "O'Malley", 56],
              [7432, "O'Malley", 39],
              [9824, "Darkes", 38]]

    assert is_equal(result, union(GRADUATES, MANAGERS))


def test_intersection():
    """
    Test intersection operation.
    """
    result = [["Number", "Surname", "Age"],
              [7432, "O'Malley", 39],
              [9824, "Darkes", 38]]

    assert is_equal(intersection(GRADUATES, MANAGERS), result)
```

If I put the test_union function first, and the test_intersection function second, the latter fails. Here is the output from py.test. It looks like the result variable in test_intersection is using the value from the test_union function.

```
/Users/ses/anaconda/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm Educational.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py" -p pytest_teamcity /Users/ses/PycharmProjects/pytest_weirdness/test_exercise3.py
Testing started at 1:11 PM ...
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10 -- py-1.4.27 -- pytest-2.7.1
rootdir: /Users/ses/PycharmProjects/pytest_weirdness, inifile: 
collected 3 items

../../../../Users/ses/PycharmProjects/pytest_weirdness/test_exercise3.py .F
def test_intersection():
        """
        Test intersection operation.
        """
        result = [["Number", "Surname", "Age"],
                  [7432, "O'Malley", 39],
                  [9824, "Darkes", 38]]

    >       assert is_equal(intersection(GRADUATES, MANAGERS), result)
    E       assert is_equal([['Number', 'Surname', 'Age'], [7432, "O'Malley", 39], [9824, 'Darkes', 38], [9297, "O'Malley", 56]], [['Number', 'Surname', 'Age'], [7432, "O'Malley", 39], [9824, 'Darkes', 38]])
    E        +  where [['Number', 'Surname', 'Age'], [7432, "O'Malley", 39], [9824, 'Darkes', 38], [9297, "O'Malley", 56]] = intersection([['Number', 'Surname', 'Age'], [7274, 'Robinson', 37], [7432, "O'Malley", 39], [9824, 'Darkes', 38], [9297, "O'Malley", 56]], [['Number', 'Surname', 'Age'], [9297, "O'Malley", 56], [7432, "O'Malley", 39], [9824, 'Darkes', 38]])
```

If I reverse the order, both tests pass. If I run one test at a time, the test case passes.

This is very confusing to me because I thought the order of test cases didn't matter. Also, I don't have the problem with my own code. The assignment isn't due until tonight, so I'm not sharing the solution yet, but [the original repo is also available on GitHub](https://github.com/benevolentprof/inf1340_2015_asst2).

I'm using Anaconda 2.3.0 distribution and PyCharm Educational Edition with Python 2.7.10 and pytest-2.7.1

Comment: if their `union` or `intersection` functions actually change the values of `GRADUTES` or `MANAGERS` then calling the second test case can fail since the expected results would not be right.

Comment: But doesn't Python call by value? Also, I've printed out the contents of the tables, and they look fine. The wierdness is the results table isn't right. I'll add the error message to the post.

Comment: depends on what type you are passing in. since `lists` are technically mutable then you can do inplace changes with things like `list.sort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a `list`, which is mutable, but functions under test have side-effect on them.

One possible solution would be to pass a *deepcopy* of the list to the tested function. Using [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module from standard library.

E.g.

```
assert is_equal(result, union(copy.deepcopy(GRADUATES), copy.deepcopy(MANAGERS)))
```

Comment: I spent all my time staring at the test_intersection code. The problem can be resolved either in test_union, in the manner that you suggest, or in union, by making a copy of the input.